# With Identity Server 3 can I use same client credentials for obtaining bearer token and performing Open ID Connect auth

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, identityserver3

I'm admittedly early in my research of Identity Server but I've worked through a few tutorials and feel I'm well over the first hurdle. I started with Identity Server's [Getting Started guide](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) and moved on to Scott Brady's excellent 3-part tutorial [starting here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1) which demonstrates how to set up an identity server with hybrid client for OIC authentication.

I therefore now have two working examples. One uses the ID and secrets of a client which uses `Flows.ClientCredentials` and `AccessTokenType.Reference` via `IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient` to obtain a bearer token for authenticating API calls (as per IS3's first Getting Started example). The other uses a client with `Flows.Hybrid` and `AccessTokenType.Jwt` to perform Open ID authentication for an MVC web app (as per Scott Brady's 3rd in his series).

What I'm working towards is providing an identity server which will let third parties write applications that can get bearer tokens for client-authorized calls to my API calls, but which will also allow its own users to authenticate using Open ID against my identity server. The way I'm currently set up I'd need to issue these 3rd parties with 2 sets of client credentials (ID and secrets) to allow them to perform these separate functions.

Is that the correct approach? My naive assumption was that this was the purpose of a hybrid flow client. However, if I call my sample code above (the one which uses `TokenClient`) using the credentials of my hybrid client the returned error is 'unauthorized_client' and Identity Server logs tell me "Client not authorized for client credentials flow".

These are how my 2 clients are defined:

```
            new Client {
                ClientId = @"cc-client",
                ClientName = @"Example Client Credentials Client",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                    new Secret("idsrv3test".Sha256())
                },
                Enabled = true,
                Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                    Scopes.SCOPE_CLIENT_STANDARD
                },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference
            },
            // Testing with a hybrid client here which will log in via our Identity Server
            // https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-3
            new Client {
                ClientId = @"hybridclient",
                ClientName = @"Example Hybrid Client",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                    new Secret("idsrv3test".Sha256())
                },
                Enabled = true,
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
                RequireConsent = true,
                AllowRememberConsent = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<string> {
                    "https://3p-client2.not-domain.local/"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {
                    "https://3p-client2.not-domain.local/"
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Roles,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
            }
```

It'd be great if someone could clear up my understanding here. Thanks.

Comment: What flow does your third client is going to use?

Comment: I may have posted too soon. I believe this property may be my saving grace - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Models/Client.cs#L79 - adding it to my hybridclient with value true appears to now let me use this client for obtaining bearer token. Can anyone confirm this is the intention?

Comment: I added client.AllowClientCredentialsOnly = true; to get mine to work - but I think my scenario is different than yours.